# What is the best way to create thumbnail for every video store on amazon s3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, thumbnails, video-processing, video-thumbnails

I use amazon s3 with sse-c to store videos, and every user has a specific customer key for sse-c. Now I want to generate thumbnail for every video, what is the best way to do it？

Does Amazon Elastic Transcoder or Elemental MediaConvert is good for me?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: You can find related [here](https://medium.com/settlin-tech/generate-image-versions-thumbnails-on-the-fly-on-aws-s3-f84eb58262)

Answer (score 0):

I found my way to solve this issue, and I write it here, Hoping it be helpful for someone.

In my case, each video may have a  specific customer key for sse-c, And some video my be huge（5GB）. So download video and then generate thumbnail on Lambda is not a good way(lambda has only 512MB disk space). Fortunately, FFmpeg can work with URL and seek,so  we have no need to download the video. I cope the sse-c video to no encryption one, and then generate presignedURL for it, and pass the url to FFmpeg,then I get the thumbnail.

Note that,copying video may take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another comment, downloading the video to process it on lambda can be problematic if the video file size is bigger than 512MB.

Amazon has an option for this, but it comes with an (expensive) cost: MediaConvert. Suppose you are transcoding a video using MediaConvert. In that case, you can add an additional output of a number of image files that will be taken using a formula you need to provide (pick an image every X frames). This is expensive for getting only a thumbnail, yet you are not sure that the thumbnails you get are good images (not blurry and representative of the video).

The solution the OP proposes, of using FFMpeg and fetch and seek the video using FFMpeg itself, will work better in comparison. It's a pretty solution if you can maintain the infrastructure to do it (some sort of processing queue, running ffmpeg, and then uploading thumbnails).

Full disclosure: We faced a similar problem. Our volume was large enough that generating thumbnails by hand was getting cumbersome, and we'd often get blank thumbnails because it's hard to predict which frame is good across different videos. So we built a product that fixes this pain for us (and others in the same boat): https://mediamachine.io/

Instead of getting random thumbnails with no meaning (and, what is worst, paying for them), we use a ML algorithm to get the most representative thumbnail of the video, saving time AND money.